# sublime text build system for jekyll

Tags: ruby, development-environment, sublimetext2

I'm trying to get a build system for the Jekyll gem in sublime text. In my sublime-project I have the following:

```
  "build_systems":
  [
    {
      "name":"jekyll",
      "cmd":"/Users/kaass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/jekyll",
      "shell":true,
      "path":"/Users/kaass/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby",
      "working_dir":"$project_path"
    }
  ]
```

I have tried playing around with `env` as well as different options above, but always get some sort of error pertaining to `ruby` or `jekyll` not found or `env: ruby_noexec_wrapper not found`

I'm running 10.8.2 and my path :

```
kaass:~ kaass$ echo $PATH
/Users/kaass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/kaass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/Users/kaass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/kaass/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

Everything I'm trying to call is already in my path.

Comment: I have had a hard time with ST2 and the PATH it uses when it starts up.  I ended up adding the .rvm bin directories to my $PATH (ruby, gem, and global), which helped me.  Not sure at all if this will help you.

Comment: Updated questions with my path. Unless ST2 modifies the path or finds it elsewhere I should have no problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem running rake within the correct rvm environment.
This is the sublime-project file I ended up with:

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "path": "data"
    }
  ],
  "build_systems":
  [
    {
      "name": "rake",
      "cmd": "source ~/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p194@mygemset && rake",
      "shell": true,
      "path": "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:~/.rvm/bin",
      "working_dir": "$project_path"
    }
  ]
}
```

The trick was to add ~/.rvm/bin to the path and to source the environment of the rvm gemset.
Then I can even use the "rake" command without specifying a full path.
The rest is straight-forward.

Comment: I used a slightly different `"cmd":"source /Users/kaass/.rvm/environments/default && jekyll"`

Comment: There seems to be common confusion about Sublime paths.  The path as seen by build systems started by Sublime is **not** the same as the PATH in your shell.